# How to call a function from command line passing in named optional parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters

I have a Python (2.7) file with a function. I want to call it from command line and pass optional parameters by param name.

In my py file, I have this function:

```
def split_file(source_file_path, alt_output_path='', chunk_size=2000000):
```

and at the bottom I have this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    split_file(*sys.argv[1:])
```

How can set it up to be able to call it like this?

```
> C:\Python27\python C:\Work\file_splitter.py "C:\Work\files\myfile.txt" alt_output_path="C:\EBI\Work\files\alt"
```

I've looked at `argparser` and it's a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Then try to work with argparser and ask question about that. It is the best way to do it.

Comment: There are some good third-party getting-started tutorials for `argparse`. (Unfortunately, there are also some horrible ones that are just effectively spam to get you to read targeted ads, because that's how the internet works nowadays… but I think most of the top hits on Google, or the links on any reputable site, will be good ones.)

Comment: But meanwhile, have you even tried the [official `argparse` tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) from the HOWTOs docs? It's a whole lot easier to get the idea from that, than from reading the reference manual and trying to work out what the examples mean.

Comment: If you took out the `alt_output_path=`, your attempt would be almost correct. Though needing to coerce `chunk_size` from string to integer is a potential issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
to_split_args = [a.split("=") for a in sys.argv[1:]]
args = [a[0] for a in to_split_args if len(a) == 1]
kwargs = dict(a for a in to_split_args if len(a) == 2)
split_file(*args,**kwargs)
```

But you should really look into argparser

Comment: The OP's code expects `chunk_size` to be an integer; as I read this, it would end up a string.